# Run MS-Windows programs directly from MS-Windows drive, on Linux

Tags: windows, wine, compatibility

I can't seem to find anything about getting WINE to use an actual MS-Windows install, instead of emulating a Windows directory system on Gnu/Linux. Is that even a good idea?

I have two SSDs: one with Arch Linux, the other with Microsoft's Windows 10. All the dependencies for the MS-Windows programs are there, since each storage drive is standalone. Can I get Wine to run programs natively from MS-Windows, and just use my Gnu/Linux install as a display server?

Comment: So you have dual-boot with Windows and Linux on two different disks, you're on Linux and want to use Windows, right? I don't know much about Windows but I'd try to move Windows to the virtual machine and run it next to Linux. I'd do that because it's possible some Windows programs may not be easy to emalute without the entire Windows runtime.

Comment: I see. Do you think I can make Linux count my physical disk with Windows on it as a virtual machine then? I'm trying to make the performance as high as possible without having to boot into Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't recommend Wine. But to answer you question. Yes mount the MS-Windows partition, then it will look like a regular directory. Point Wine at this directory. There may be problems caused by Gnu/Linux writing to this partition. So mount it read-only.

If you need to write to it (but not so MS-Windows can see), then use a union-file-system, to layer a write layer on top.

## A better solution

If you want to keep MS-Windows, then put it in virtual-box.

Comment: I suppose that really is the best solution. There are some workflows I'm used to that only exist in Windows programs I've found, but I like Arch Linux as an operating system much better.